# Найти углы треугольника

Tags: javascript

Даны длины сторон треугольника и необходимо найти углы треугольника.
При решении этой задачи я использую теорему косинусов

```js
    let triangleAngles = (a, b, c) => {
        let a1, a2, a3, cosA, cosB, cosC;
        cosA = (b*b + c*c - a*a) / (2*b*c);
        cosB = (a*a + c*c - b*b) / (2*a*c);
        cosC = (a*a + b*b - c*c) / (2*a*b);
    
        a1 = (b*b) + (c*c) - ((2*b*c) * Math.cos(cosA));
        a2 = (b*b) + (c*c) - ((2*c*a) * Math.cos(cosB));
        a3 = (b*b) + (a*a) - ((2*b*a) * Math.cos(cosC));
    
        return [Math.round(a1), Math.round(a2), Math.round(a3)];
    }
    
    console.log(triangleAngles(4,4,4));
    console.log(triangleAngles(3,4,5));
```

Первый вариант считает правильно возвращает углы в 60 градусов, в вот при втором случае получается массив [68, 65, 49], это не верно. Подскажите, где ошибся в расчётах :)

Comment: Я бы воспользовался не теоремой косинусов, а определением скалярного произведения из которого следует, что cos между векторами x и y вычисляется по формуле cos = (x,y)/sqrt(||x||*||y||)

Comment: @Александр Муксимов Координат у автора нет. Можно построить треугольник с данными сторонами и получить векторы, но это лишняя работа.

Comment: Вы считаете косинус от косинуса. Это какой-то бессмысленный боед

Comment: С какой целью вы берете косинус от косинуса? Что вообще считается в строчках а1, b1, c1? И этот код не выдает ни 60 градусов, ни 68, 65, 49.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы посчитать углы, нужно к значению косинуса (`cosA` и т.д.) применить функцию арккосинус (`Math.acos`). Результат будет в радианах, их можно перевести в градусы, умножив на 180 и разделив на Pi

```
angleA = Math.acos(cosA) * 180 / Math.PI;
```

```js
   let triangleAngles = (a, b, c) => {
        let a1, a2, a3, cosA, cosB, cosC;
        cosA = (b*b + c*c - a*a) / (2*b*c);
        cosB = (a*a + c*c - b*b) / (2*a*c);
        cosC = (a*a + b*b - c*c) / (2*a*b);
    
        angleA = Math.acos(cosA) * 180 / Math.PI;
        angleB = Math.acos(cosB) * 180 / Math.PI;
        angleC = Math.acos(cosC) * 180 / Math.PI;
    
        return [Math.round(angleA), Math.round(angleB), Math.round(angleC)];
    }
    
    console.log(triangleAngles(4,4,4));
    console.log(triangleAngles(3,4,5));
```

---

Выражения же для a1,a2,a3 бессмысленны.

Вот так:

```
a1 = (b*b) + (c*c) - (2*b*c) * cosA;
```

можно посчитать квадрат третьей стороны, но она и так известна

Comment: "Выражения же для a1,a2,a3 бессмысленны."
MBo - вы не правы, информацию брал отсюда http://www.webmath.ru/poleznoe/formules_19_7.php
Math.acos не даёт результата

Comment: Я прав. На той странице описывается, как применить арккосинус. Результат будет в радианах, их нужно перевести в градусы.

Comment: спасибо, разобрался

Comment: угол, соответствующий  гипотенузе (лежащий напротив неё), самой длинной  стороне (5) - прямой, 90 градусов.